# How do I fake an specific browser client when using Java's Net library?

Tags: java, http, http-headers

A small program of mine just broke because, it seems, the site I was programmatically browsing now assumes a Java request comes from a mobile phone, and the link I was looking for is not on their mobile page.

So I want to fake an Internet Explorer access. How do I do that with java.net?

Comment: Why do it that way instead of using, say, Apache HttpClient? BTW it's mainly the user agent HTTP header you want to set.

Comment: Well, for one thing I avoid having to pack another library. For a second thing, the code I'm am using works through java.net, so this makes for less change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, set `"http.agent"` system property through `System`, `-D` on the command line, in your JNLP file or elsewhere.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you're using java.net.URLConnection, then call setRequestProperty(String,String) to set the request header to a value that IE would use. For example, to fake IE6:

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 1.2.30703)");
```

and then use the connection object as before.

But java.net is horrible. Use Apache Commons HttpClient instead, it's much nicer.

Even better, use a framework designed for navigating websites, like HtmlUnit

Comment: Ah - good call. I didn't know about connection.setRequestProperty - I've always used HttpClient by default.

Comment: It's pretty obscure, but this is because URLConnection isn't necessarily HTTP, so the method name is generic.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the [User-Agent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#user-agent) header in the HTTP request to a [value used by Internet Explorer](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/).

I recommend using the [Jakarta HttpClient library](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) to make the request as it provides a higher level API for [manipulating](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/AbstractHttpMessage.html?is-external=true#setHeader(org.apache.http.Header)) the request.