# Send Http header for identification

Tags: java, http-headers, httprequest

I have this code for reading webpage. I need to send http header to server because of identification. How should i do that? do i need to use socket? beacuse that's what i found so far.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.page.com/");

URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));

String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
      System.out.println(inputLine);
in.close();
```

I found this code for sending http request header.

```
Socket sock = new Socket(url.getHost(), port);
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream()));
out.writeBytes("GET " + url.getFile() + " HTTP/1.0\n");
out.writeBytes("User-Agent: " + user_agent + "\n");
out.writeBytes("From: " + email_address + "\n");
out.writeBytes("Host: " + url.getHost() + "\n");
out.writeBytes("\n");
out.flush();
```

I dont know if i can combine this two codes somehow, or i need to change way of reading page to be able to send header.

Thanks!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144073

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what 'because of identification' means, but if you know what header fields you need, you can add them with:

```
URLConnection conn = new URLConnection(url);
conn.addRequestProperty("myHeaderField", "myHeaderValue");
conn.openConnection()
```